# Retrieve audio - binary file- stored in my Mlab

Tags: node.js, mongodb, audio, download, mlab

Basically, I have set an application with the MediaDevices.getUserMedia WebRTC API. I have recorded the audios and all, all is good in theory. But I got to retrieve the audio now to listen to them.

I wonder now how to download audio Post in my MongoDB database. I have tried to export my MongoDB database but I receive only JSON or CSV file, not my audios files.

I have heard about gridFS but only in image-handling context. Before dive deeply into gridFS I would get your thinks about audio retrieving with Mlab. and MongoDB more widely.
    Also, gridFS seems to be designed for large files, but in my case, I just want to store ridiculously little files of some hundreds of bytes, so gridFS seems maybe overkilled? Maybe there is a more efficient solution?

EDIT : I struggle to translate my data in order to store it in my database.

So far, my console return me :

```
XML Parsing Error: syntax error
```

Here my App.js :

```
// post section

async handleSubmit(e){

e.preventDefault();

Axios.post("/api/words",{

"sound":this.state.blob

})

//.then((res) => res.json())

.then((data) => console.log(data))

//pass submitted value to true in order to declench allDelete function

}


(...) 


// blob formatting section :

saveAudio() {

// convert saved chunks to blob

const blob = new Blob(this.chunks, {type: audioType});

this.setState({blob : blob})
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need GridFS for files smaller than 16 MB. You can either store binary data directly in MongoDB using [BSON's binary type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/) or encode your binary data and store it as a string. Base64 is a common encoding choice when storing binary data as strings.

Once you retrieve the data from the database, you can write it to a file using [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback).

If you saved your data as a binary type, you can pass a [buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer) to `fs.writeFile`. If you saved your data as an encoded string, you can pass a string and an `encoding` option.

(If you wanted to serve the file with Express, you can set the content type and send the data using [`res.send`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send))

Here's a small example in NodeJS. This reads an audio file from disk, saves it to a MongoDB database as a binary type (using the MongoDB driver's [Binary](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Binary.html) class), retrieves it back from the database, and writes it to a new file on disk.

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb')
const util = require('util')
const fs = require('fs')
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile)
const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile)

async function main() {
  const client = await mongodb.MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
  console.log('connected')

  let db = await client.db('dbname')

  // Reading in binary data from a file. data is a buffer.
  let data = await readFile(__dirname + '/sample.mp3')

  // Insert binary data to the database
  let res = await db.collection('coll').insert({data: new mongodb.Binary(data)})
  console.log(res)
  let objectId = res.ops[0]._id

  // Retrieve binary data from the database
  let obj = await db.collection('coll').findOne({_id: objectId})
  console.log(obj)

  // *** This is the key part ***
  // use obj.data.read to get a buffer from the binary data and write that buffer to a file
  await writeFile(__dirname + '/out.mp3', obj.data.read(0, obj.data.length()))

  console.log('done')
}

main()
```

Although people do store binary data in the database, it's probably most common for people to store files in a file system or in object storage (such as Amazon S3). Then they would just store a link to that file in the database and retrieve that file using the link. You can do whichever you feel more comfortable with.

Comment: Waw thank you for this complete answer, I will test it

Comment: Hi tfogo, I have a question please, it seems is more easy to translate data into binary data with MongoDB rather than mongoose? I struggle to translate data into binary using mongoose. I will test your MongoDB way to do it.

Comment: It's about the same - Use the Buffer type in the mongoose schema and just pass in a buffer as the object. You can see an example in the Mongoose docs: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html