# Express server to return file not an HTML page

Tags: node.js, express

So I would like to host audio files on my server.

Here's how I do it.

```
app.use("/media/audio", express.static("media/audio"));
```

I have done it tons of times with images and I really haven't had a problem so far.

I am able to play these files in browser but I need little more than that.

I am not even sure how to describe it but what I need is this:

[image]

My URL only returns media player but nothing in `Sources` tab like shown in the picture.

The only reason I want it is because Android MediaPlayer cannot return .mp3 file just because the URL ends with .mp3. Apple doesn't have a problem with that and it plays fine.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you want to play it accordingly to the device, so you should try write the response based on your device type (using nodejs filesystem): https://stackoverflow.com/a/50537909/3332734

Comment: In case you want to retrieve the duration of a MP3/WAV Audio File in the Browser: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1036/how-to-retrieve-the-duration-of-a-mp3-wav-audio-file-in-the-browser-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

instead of `app.use("/media/audio", express.static("media/audio"));`

use

```
app.use("/media/audio", (req, res)=>{
  res.download("/media/audio.mp3");
});
```